# Trying to emulate linear regression using Keras

Tags: regression, neural-networks, linear-model, deep-learning

I am trying to build a very simple NN to approximate a linear function (literally).

I took a table data:

[image]

f(x) = 5 * x

Shapes:

[image]

Now I am building a very simple NN using Keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense

# define base mode
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

regr = baseline_model()
regr.fit(X_train, Y_train,          
          nb_epoch=200, validation_split=0.2, verbose = 1) #batch_size=5,
```

And getting a totally wasted output:

```
Epoch 197/200
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 34810.5195 - val_loss: 131652.9375
Epoch 198/200
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 34809.8574 - val_loss: 131651.5000
Epoch 199/200
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 34809.2266 - val_loss: 131650.0781
Epoch 200/200
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 34808.5801 - val_loss: 131648.6406
```

Which is confirmed by plotting it:

```
plt.scatter(X_test, Y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, regr.predict(X_test), color='blue',
         linewidth=3)

plt.xticks()
plt.yticks()

plt.show()
```

I have two hypothesis:

- My model is very very wrong.
- I am working with Keras not the way it was designed.

Please help.

Comment: Output plot could be found at here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Zwv.png

Answer (score 0):

You seem to read data with *Pandas* and, probably, there is a mess with your input. You should definitely try generating it using *numpy*:

```
import numpy as np

X_train = np.linspace(0, 80, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
Y_train = 5 * X_train
```

For linear approximation single neuron is ok:

```
# define base mode
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, init='normal', activation='relu', input_shape=(100,)))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

Worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to remove the hidden layer? After all, it is a linear relation.

Comment: @Pieter Sure, didn't notice right away.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Why isn't the activation `'linear'`, since we are trying to replicate linear regression?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida It definitely should be *linear*. Didn't notice in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: @DenisKulagin Hi, what are your `model.fit()` parameters to fit this line so well ?

Comment: @DenisKulagin In Keras v2.1, I get a `TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input_dim')`